# How to force CoTURN long term credentials validation from WebRTC Flutter application?

Tags: flutter, webrtc, coturn

I use [this example of Flutter data channel](https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/flutter-webrtc-demo/blob/master/lib/src/basic_sample/data_channel_sample.dart) to connect my Android app to my [CoTURN server](https://github.com/coturn/coturn) on my local network. The CoTURN logs show that the Android app connects successfully to the CoTURN server but doesn't show any username. I would like to make sure that no access is possible to my CoTURN server while not using long term credentials.

The version of my CoTURN server is 4.5.1.1-1.1 on Debian Linux Stable (10 Buster). The `lt-cred-mech` is already set in the CoTURN server configuration while `no-auth` is not set (it is commented). I am using `verbose` to check the logs. I have a user created in my MySQL database for long term credentials. It is verified using this command on the secured port:

```
turnutils_uclient -p 5349 -u myuser -w mypassword 192.168.188.28
```

It leads to the following in the coturn logs:

```
1992: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr 192.168.188.28:5349, remote addr 192.168.188.28:58256
1992: session 002000000000000002: realm <myrealm> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
1992: IPv4. Local relay addr: 192.168.188.28:64632
1992: IPv4. Local reserved relay addr: 192.168.188.28:64633
1992: session 002000000000000002: new, realm=<myrealm>, username=<myuser>, lifetime=777
1992: session 002000000000000002: realm <myrealm> user <myuser>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
1992: session 002000000000000002: refreshed, realm=<myrealm>, username=<myuser>, lifetime=777
1992: session 002000000000000002: realm <myrealm> user <myuser>: incoming packet REFRESH processed, success
...
2007: session 003000000000000003: delete: realm=<myrealm>, username=<myuser>
2007: session 003000000000000003: peer 0.0.0.0:3481 deleted
2008: session 001000000000000008: usage: realm=<myrealm>, username=<myuser>, rp=13, rb=1360, sp=8, sb=768
2008: session 001000000000000008: closed (2nd stage), user <myuser> realm <myrealm> origin <>, local 192.168.188.28:5349, remote 192.168.188.28:48266, reason: allocation timeout
2008: session 001000000000000008: delete: realm=<myrealm>, username=<myuser>
2008: session 001000000000000008: peer 0.0.0.0:3481 deleted
```

If I try the same command with an intentionally invalid user, I get the expected following results in the server logs:

```
2227: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr 192.168.188.28:5349, remote addr 192.168.188.28:40431
2227: session 002000000000000003: realm <myrealm> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
2227: check_stun_auth: Cannot find credentials of user <myuserfaulty>
2227: session 002000000000000003: realm <myrealm> user <myuserfaulty>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
2227: check_stun_auth: Cannot find credentials of user <myuserfaulty>
...
```

So, this means that the credentials are indeed checked by the CoTURN server.

However, when I add credentials to the Flutter app as follows, I get server logs that don't seem to show any user. Worst, if the user is intentionally faulty, it changes nothing. Here is the portion of code adapted:

```
...
    Map<String, dynamic> configuration = {
      "iceServers": [
        {"url": "stun:192.168.188.28:5349"},
        {"username": "myuserfaulty"},
        {"credential": "mypassword"},
      ]
    };
...
```

Note that I guessed the `username` and `credential` entries in the configuration from the following files:

https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/flutter-webrtc/blob/master/ios/Classes/FlutterWebRTCPlugin.m

https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/flutter-webrtc/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/cloudwebrtc/webrtc/FlutterWebRTCPlugin.java

Here are the CoTURN logs while using intentionally wrong credentials from Flutter:

```
2945: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr 192.168.188.28:5349, remote addr 192.168.188.31:58350
2945: session 002000000000000004: realm <myrealm> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
2955: session 002000000000000004: realm <myrealm> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
2965: session 002000000000000004: realm <myrealm> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
2975: session 002000000000000004: realm <myrealm> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
2985: session 002000000000000004: realm <myrealm> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
2995: session 002000000000000004: realm <myrealm> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
3005: session 002000000000000004: usage: realm=<myrealm>, username=<>, rp=6, rb=120, sp=6, sb=528
3005: session 002000000000000004: closed (2nd stage), user <> realm <myrealm> origin <>, local 192.168.188.28:5349, remote 192.168.188.31:58350, reason: allocation watchdog determined stale session state
3005: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr 192.168.188.28:5349, remote addr 192.168.188.31:58350
3005: session 002000000000000005: realm <myrealm> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
3015: session 002000000000000005: realm <myrealm> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
...
```

So, I have the following questions:

1. How can I make sure that my CoTURN server cannot be used without authorized long term credentials?
2. How come the Flutter app is not subject to the same credentials validation as the `turnutils_uclient`?
3. Did I guess correctly the way to specify the credentials in the Flutter app with the addition of the `username` and `credential` entries in the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. With this configuration (`lt-cred-mech`), the TURN server cannot be used without authorized long term credentials. However, the STUN server never requires authentication.
2. The `turnutils_uclient` command requires authentication because it calls the TURN server. To make a STUN server test call, the `turnutils_stunclient` command can be used and no credentials can be given to it.
3. The format for long term authentication on TURN server in Flutter is described in a comment in this file:
   https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/flutter-webrtc-demo/blob/master/lib/src/call_sample/signaling.dart

```
...
      {
        'url': 'turn:123.45.67.89:3478',
        'username': 'change_to_real_user',
        'credential': 'change_to_real_secret'
      },
...
```

which shows that my attempts were wrong for two reasons:

- The protocol must be set to turn instead of stun.
- The configuration items must be in the same array.

After those corrections, I do get the username in the coturn server logs as shown below:

```
87055: session 000000000000000540: new, realm=<myrealm>, username=<myuser>, lifetime=600
87055: session 000000000000000540: realm <myrealm> user <myuser>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
87065: session 000000000000000540: realm <myrealm> user <myuser>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
```

Note that the coturn server configuration can require authentication for the STUN binding request as well:

```
...
# Require authentication of the STUN Binding request.
# By default, the clients are allowed anonymous access to the STUN Binding functionality.
#
#secure-stun
...
```